# Iterate on nested json through python

Tags: python, json

I am having a json data coming through API and i need to print some specific values through it and i am using the code to get the same but its giving me keyerror : results

```
import json
import requests
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}
r = requests.get('API', headers=headers)
data=r.text
parse_json=json.loads(data)
for result in parse_json['results']:
    for cpu in result['cpumfs']:
        print(cpu.get('pct_im_utilization'))
```

Below is the json data :

```
{'d': {'__count': '0', 'results': [{'ID': '6085', 'Name': 'device1', 'DisplayName': None, 'DisplayDescription': None, 'cpumfs': {'results': [{'ID': '6117', 'Timestamp': '1649157300', 'DeviceItemID': '6085', 'pct_im_Utilization': '4.0'}, {'ID': '6117', 'Timestamp': '1649157600', 'DeviceItemID': '6085', 'pct_im_Utilization': '1.0'}, {'ID': '6117', 'Timestamp': '1649157900', 'DeviceItemID': '6085', 'pct_im_Utilization': '4.0'}, {'ID': '6117', 'Timestamp': '1649158200', 'DeviceItemID': '6085', 'pct_im_Utilization': '1.0'},
```

I need to get printed Name of the device ,Timestamp,pct_im_utlization

Comment: Please, take a look at the stack trace: it will tell you in which line the error ocurred; that should give you a better idea of which keys are failing to be found.

Comment: The 'results' key is nested under the 'd' key. You should call parse_json['d']['results'] to get the results

Comment: @CameronFord - Just noticed that and modified the line to below :
for result in parse_json['d']['results']:
Getting the below error now:
print(cpu.get('pct_im_utilization'))
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: You could try to add a `print(cpu)`, before the `print(cpu.get('pct_im_utilization'))`, just to have an idea of what `cpu` contains.

Comment: I think the data you have posted is truncated, as there are no closing ]s?

Comment: Furthermore, it seems that the "results" with ID 6117 are nested under the "results" with ID 6085. So you will need to loop for the outer results entries and then loop for the inner ones to get your data

Comment: i am able to get the data with the below code :
for result in parse_json['d']['results']:
for cpu in result['cpumfs']['results']:
cpu_utilization=cpu['pct_im_Utilization']
Timestamp=cpu['Timestamp']
print(cpu_utilization,Timestamp,result.get('Name'))

But this is only printing the values which are coming and not the specific keys such as device name,"Timestamp",pct_im_utilization.I need this for identification

Comment: My code is not correlating the device name to the pct_im_utilization values inside the json.There should be some another way to do it.Mine is randomly picking the device name and associating it with Timestamp,pct_im_utilization